# Free BSD/ Mac OS X Sed: Print regex match and the line 5 lines after the match

Tags: text-processing, sed

I thought it would be `sed -n /mymatch/,+5p` but I get expected context address.  At this point I am just guessing commands, nothing works!  I want to grab every line that matches the regex and print that line and the line which comes 5 lines after it, globally from a file.

Answer (score 3):

Might be easier with `awk`:

```
awk '/foo/ {print; p[NR+5]; next}; NR in p'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brute force approach:

```
sed -n '/mymatch/ {p;n;n;n;n;n;p;}'
```

Demo

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo mymatch 1 2 mymatch 4 5 6
foo
mymatch
1
2
mymatch
4
5
6

$ printf '%s\n' foo mymatch 1 2 mymatch 4 5 6 | sed -n '/mymatch/ {p;n;n;n;n;n;p;}'
mymatch
```

Comment: sed: 1: "/[A-Z][0-9]/ {p;n;p;n;p ...": extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: You needed a ; at the end.  Ill make the edit

Comment: What is the p;n sequence doing here to print the 5th sequent line in sed? does p;n mean **not print**?

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. That would print the matched line and all of the next 5 lines. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the lines between, you can do this:

```
perl -lne '$a=5 if /foo/; print if $a==0||$a==5; $a--' file.txt
```

or, if you prefer slurping:

```
perl -e '@f=<>; for($i=0;$i<=$#f;$i++){print "$f[$i]$f[$i+5]" if $f[$i]=~/foo/}' file
```

Comment: I dont want the lines between, I want lines matching /regex/ and the line that comes 5 lines after the regex, not the next 5 consecutive lines.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal ah, sorry, see updated answer.